# customer redirect multi store magento

Tags: multistore, login, redirect

I have set up a multi store in magento, so I have example.com and example.com/wholesaler what I need to do is have everyone who is in customer group ***wholesale*** redirected to example.com/wholesaler from the example.com store.

I originally tried this http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/custom-login-redirect-extension.html works perfectly for redirecting on the example.com site, but because when you login the url changes to example.com/index.php it creates example.com/index.php/wholesaler which is a 404.

Does anyone have a solution to get my customers in the wholesale group across to my other store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could look at turning SEO friendly URL's on to remove the index.php from the url.

Navigate to  `System > Configuration > General > Web > Search Engine Optimisation` and underneath `Use Webserver Rewrites option` and select `Yes`

In your `.htaccess` make sure RewriteBase is as follows `RewriteBase /`.

You should now be able to get to `example.com/wholesaler` without the index.php

Comment: Once you've enabled SEO friendly URL's you can actually also offload the redirection off of apache via integrated DNS / CDN / Accelerator services like CloudFlare.com  I'm not sure if their free plan support this feature, but we pay for the DDoS protection and it's definitely supported there - essentially, once you turn on SEO-friendly URLs it doesn't matter if you enter the old url and apache re-writes it or if you use Cloudflares DNS-based 301, 302 redirection (which is faster).  There may be a SEO penalty if you switch after launch but we do it on all new build and it works fine for us.

Comment: I know i do the same i make sure this is enabled before launching a site and i think cloudflare free account does this. I'm not sure if there would be penalties but would be interested to know..

Comment: You'd think that any penalties incurred would be made up by the performance increase you would get from having CloudFlare put 2 nginx reverse proxies in each of their data centers to proxy requests & feed CDN primed media assets, but that might depend on the age of the urls i supposed and the authority they had accumulated. I try and learn as much about the SEO stuff that i can but mostly I try and let our team who specializes in that handle it .... unless there's a "PERFORMANCE TEST" to be done ;)